# how does electronic conductance of a metal change with density?

Tags: electrochemistry

The electronic conductance of a metal depends on its density.Does this mean that if we increase the density of the metal,its electronic conductance will increase?How does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the density of a metal without also changing other properties.

Brass is a mixture of several elements. It can have different densities depending on the mixture of the elements. I haven't researched it, but the electronic conductance would likely be different for each type of brass.

Do you have a source for your statement?

> The electronic conductance of a metal depends on its density.

Comment: It's given in a reference book of chemistry.

Comment: @user47568 I'd be curious what the book is. On the one hand, I can imagine that making a less dense metal (i.e., adding impurities, voids, filling with air, etc.) would likely create a less conductive material, I don't think compressing a metal and increasing the density necessarily makes a more conductive material. Maybe this is true in some cases, but recent experiments and quantum calculations have shown complicated effects with high pressure materials.